# Blend SVG paths together to feel like 1 line

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path d="M56,56 C112,56 28,28 56,56" fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="2px"></path>
  <path d="M56,56 C112,56 8,1.5 16,3" fill="none" stroke="#FF7F00" stroke-width="2px"></path>
  <path d="M16,3 C32,3 8,24 16,48" fill="none" stroke="#FF7F00" stroke-width="2px"></path>
  <path d="M16,48 C32,48 6,2.5 12,5" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="2px"></path>
</svg>
```

If you look closely, the lines abruptly end. You can see how they square off, like so:

[image]

Is there a way to make paths blend together?

**EDIT**: Ideally, I would want to find a way to automate this. The way I form the `d` value in the path is with the following:

```js
const points = [
  [56,56],
  [16,3],
  [16,48],
  [12,5],
]

const generateLines = (points) => {
  const lines = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0)
      lines.push({x1: points[i][0], y1: points[i][1], x2: points[i][0], y2: points[i][1]});
    else 
      lines.push({
        x1: lines[i-1].x2, 
        y1: lines[i-1].y2, 
        x2: points[i][0], 
        y2: points[i][1]
      });
  }

  return lines;
}

console.log(generateLines(points));

//<path d=M{x1},{y1} C{x1*2},{y1} {x2/2},{y2/2} {x2},{y2}
```

Comment: you can try adding `stroke-linecap="round"`

Comment: Automate? So, what would the data look like? How are x1, y1 etc. and the colors represented?

Comment: @chrwahl I edited the post to explain how the data looks like. Colors are just random.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathLength` (total length of path), `stroke-dasharray` (dash defined by length of dash and following space) and `stroke-dashoffset` (negative number along the path) on the same path to specify there a color should start and end.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m 42 57 C 112 56 29 49 62 48 C 109 47 2 3 16 3 C 32 3 3 48 16 48 C 32 48 4 8 12 5"
  fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="2px" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="25 100" stroke-dashoffset="0"></path>
  <path d="m 42 57 C 112 56 29 49 62 48 C 109 47 2 3 16 3 C 32 3 3 48 16 48 C 32 48 4 8 12 5" 
  fill="none" stroke="#FF7F00" stroke-width="2px" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="25 100" stroke-dashoffset="-25"></path>
  <path d="m 42 57 C 112 56 29 49 62 48 C 109 47 2 3 16 3 C 32 3 3 48 16 48 C 32 48 4 8 12 5" 
  fill="none" stroke="#FF7F00" stroke-width="2px" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="25 100" stroke-dashoffset="-50"></path>
  <path d="m 42 57 C 112 56 29 49 62 48 C 109 47 2 3 16 3 C 32 3 3 48 16 48 C 32 48 4 8 12 5" 
  fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="2px" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="25 100" stroke-dashoffset="-75"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your path `d` looks much different then mine. May I ask what you changed so I can figure out how to calculate the new values?

Comment: @bryan Yes, I did my best to stitch it together and ended up changing it a bit. Initially I just removed the beginning `Mxx,xx` for every path except the first. I used the tool [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to edit the `path` attributes **once**

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('svg-colored-line', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">` + [
        ["red", 0],
        ["green", 1],
        ["gold", 2],
        ["blue", 3]
      ].map(([stroke, offset]) => `<path d="M42 57C112 56 29 49 62 48C109 47 2 3 16 3C32 3 3 48 16 48C32 48 4 8 12 5"
              fill="none"stroke-width="5"pathLength="4"stroke-dasharray="1 4"
              stroke="${stroke}"stroke-dashoffset="-${offset}"/>`).join("") + `</svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>

<svg-colored-line></svg-colored-line>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what was done here. If I had the following variables for the path, would there be a way to calculate the stroke/offset automatically? (see edit in question).

Comment: @bryan it is the same concept that I used (pathLength and dasharray). @danny-365csi-engelman just likes  custom elements a lot. In his example the pathLength is 4, so the dasharray in just 1 unit long. But he could actually make just a simple array with the colors and then use the index of the array instead `["red","green","gold"].map((color, index) => {...})`

Comment: I do like code that makes (my coding) life easier. That happens to be (vanilla) Web Components for Front-End development. I deliberately left out all spaces between SVG attributes, to show you can write compacter code than a minifier produces.